# Using Variables instead of pattern in Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex

I am fairly new to python.  I have searched several forums and have not quite found the answer.

I have a list defined and would like to search a line for occurrences in the list. Something like

```
import re
list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for xa in range(0, len(list)):
m = re.search(r, list[xa], line):
if m:
    print(m)
```

Is there anyway to pass the variable into regex?

Comment: Your question is not clear - what is the variable `r` ? you should describe  what you're trying to do (example input + output).

Comment: What are you doing with the re.search? And what do you mean "search a line for occurrences in the list"? Just fyi, proper indentation is required for your for loops, and if you pass in 3 arguments to re.search, the third argument will be interpreted as a keyword argument: flags.

Answer (score 1):

yep, you could do like this,

```
for xa in range(0, len(lst)):
    m = re.search(lst[xa], line)
    if m:
        print(m.group())
```

**Example:**

```
>>> line = 'foo bar'
>>> import re
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> for xa in range(0, len(lst)):
        m = re.search(lst[xa], line)
        if m:
            print(m.group())


a
b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build the variable into the regex parameter, for example:

```
import re
line = '1y2c3a'
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for x in lst:
    m = re.search('\d'+x, line)
    if m:
        print m.group()
```

Output:

```
3a
2c
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.  New programmers are always appreciate assistance.